# Is it possible to debug dll which loaded with custom loader?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windbg, visual-studio-debugging

I have my own implementation of LoadLibrary function (MyLoadLibrary) it successfully loads dll  (foo.dll) - performing relocation and resolving symbols. However i cannot debug code in foo.dll - visual studio (and windbg) debugger does not recognize breakpoints in foo.dll

I found that debugger can process [DEBUG_EVENT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679308%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, maybe i can generate such DEBUG_EVENT (LOAD_DLL_DEBUG_INFO) for MyLoadLibrary and send this event to debugger?

Also i found function [SymLoadModuleEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681353%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - i can set baseAddress and image size of my dll (because i loaded foo.dll by myself), i've tried to call it from debugee but it does not helps, i think that this function must be called from debugger.

Is there some way to obtain source level debugging for foo.dll?

Comment: @Alxey, have your dll .pdb file nearby?

Comment: Maybe a workaround - use the normal `LoadLibrary` to do the debugging, then switch back to your version when done.

Comment: @Dewfy - yes i have corresponding foo.pdb

Comment: Obviously Microsoft to provide debugging capability modifies LoadLibrary as well. That is why opinion of @RogerRowland looks reasonable

Comment: @RogerRowland - actually you are right, but when i load library i resolve symbols in my own way (not same as ::LoadLibrary does), so i need such approach

Comment: @Alexey sure, but debugging the DLL is not dependent on your method of loading it (or is it?) so maybe you're trying to verify that your symbols have resolved ok? Perhaps you can use `OutputDebugString` in your DLL to at least get some trace output even if you can't breakpoint.

Comment: @RogerRowland sure, because i resolve symbol differently from ::LoadLibrary approach, behavior of my foo.dll is changed. For example ::LoadLibrary resolve symbol 'bar' to proper function 'bar' which returns 1, and MyLoadLibrary resolver symbol 'bar' to function 'my_bar', which returns 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found similar solution: I performed library loading with ::[LoadLibraryEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with special flag: DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES. When this function finished i have loaded and relocated dll image in process memory, after that i manualy resolve all dll imports in my own way, also such approach preserve source level debugging.